# New to pig, how to transform JSON to another JSON with a subset of the key value pairs in pig?

Tags: json, apache-pig, avro

Assuming I have the following json:

```
{
"state":"VA",
"fruit":[
{"name":"Bannana",
"color":"Yellow",
"cost":1.6
},
{"name":"Apple",
"color":"Red"
"cost":1.4
}
]}
```

In pig, how do I transform the above to the following:

```
{
"state":"VA",
"fruit":[
{"name":"Bannana",,
"cost":1.6
},
{"name":"Apple",
"cost":1.4
}
]}
```

I've tried:

```
A = #load file
B = FOREACH A GENERATE
state,
fruit.name,
fruit.cost;
```

and the following:

```
A = #load file
B = FOREACH A GENERATE
state,
fruit as (m:bag{FruitInfo.(tuple(name:string, cost:double))});
```

Seems like no matter what I do I keep getting nested arrays. Is what I am trying to do possible? I picked pig for its ability to transform data. Note that the data is loaded with AvroStorage.

Comment: have a look here : http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/basic.html

Comment: Try Using UDF. I have posted working code as Answer. Any restrictions not to use UDF ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt whether it can be done without UDF.

Java UDF:

```
package com.example.exp1;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc;
import org.apache.pig.data.BagFactory;
import org.apache.pig.data.DataBag;
import org.apache.pig.data.DataType;
import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;
import org.apache.pig.data.TupleFactory;
import org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.schema.Schema;
import org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.schema.Schema.FieldSchema;

public class ReformatBag extends EvalFunc<DataBag> {

    @Override
    public DataBag exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {

        DataBag returnBag = BagFactory.getInstance().newDefaultBag();
        if (input == null || input.size() == 0 || input.get(0) == null)
            return null;
        try {
            // Get the bag
            DataBag bag = DataType.toBag(input.get(0));
            // Iterate throughout the bag
            Iterator it = bag.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                // assign the current
                Tuple t = (Tuple) it.next();
                // Create a new Tuple of size 2 where the refactor the data
                Tuple reformatTuple = TupleFactory.getInstance().newTuple(2);
                // Add 1st field (name)
                reformatTuple.set(0, t.get(0));
                // Add 3rd field (price)
                reformatTuple.set(1, t.get(2));
                //add to the bag. Continue iterating.
                returnBag.add(reformatTuple);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IOException("Caught exception processing input row ", e);
        }
        return returnBag;
    }

    public Schema outputSchema(Schema input) {
        try {
            Schema outputSchema = new Schema();
            Schema bagSchema = new Schema();
            // Tuple schema which holds name and cost schema
            Schema innerTuple = new Schema();
            innerTuple.add(new FieldSchema("name", DataType.CHARARRAY));
            innerTuple.add(new FieldSchema("cost", DataType.FLOAT));

            // Add the tuple schema holding name & cost to the bag schema
            bagSchema.add(new FieldSchema("t1", innerTuple, DataType.TUPLE));
            // Return type of the UDF
            outputSchema.add(new FieldSchema("fruit", bagSchema, DataType.BAG));
            return outputSchema;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Pig Code :

```
REGISTER /path/to/jar/exp1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;

input_data = LOAD 'text.json'
        USING JsonLoader('state:chararray,fruit:{(name:chararray,color:chararray,cost:float)}');

reformat_data = FOREACH input_data
        GENERATE state,com.example.exp1.ReformatBag(fruit);
STORE
        reformat_data
        INTO 'output.json'
        USING JsonStorage();
```

Output :

```
{"state":"VA","fruit":[{"name":"Bannana","cost":1.6},{"name":"Apple","cost":1.4}]}
```